# Relation between $\lim a_n$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose that we are given a sequence $(a_n)$, where $a_n=\frac n{n+1}$. Then, $a_n\to 0$.

It may be observed that if we define $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R:f(x)=\frac x{x+1}$, that is $f(n)=a_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$. It follows that $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0=\lim a_n$.

**My question is:** For any given sequence $(a_n)$ and function $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ defined as $f(x)=a_x$, where $a_x=$ expression obtained by replacing $n$ by $x$ in the expression of $a_n$, is it true that $(a_n)$ converges if and only if $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)$ exists? $\tag 1$

If I were to find: $\lim_{x\to \infty}(1+\frac 1{x})^x$, then if $(1)$ were true, I would simply find this limit by $ \lim_{x\to \infty}(1+\frac 1{x})^x=\lim(1+\frac 1{n})^n=e$

If $(1)$ is not true then this is how I would calculate the aforementioned limit: For sufficiently large $x$, there exists $n$ such that $n\le x\le n+1\implies \frac 1{n+1}\le \frac 1{x}\le \frac 1{n}\implies \frac {n+2}{n+1}\le 1+\frac 1{x}\le \frac {n+1}{n}\implies (\frac {n+2}{n+1})^n\le (1+\frac 1{x})^x\le (\frac {n+1}{n})^{n+1}$. The result  follows by squeeze theorem.

If $(1)$ is not true then what are the conditions(continuity, differentiability of $f$) under which $(1)$ is true?

Comment: The answer below captures the issue nicely. If you have something relating the values of $f$ at integers to the values of $f$ at non-integer values (e.g. monotonicity) it is potentially possible to improve the result. But the assumptions must apply to $f$ at all values, not just integer values. In general there is nothing to tie the integer behavior of a function on $\mathbb{R}$ to its behavior at all other values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exists, then $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$. This includes when the limit is infinite. This direction is quite trivial with $\delta-\epsilon$.

On the other hand, it's possible for $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ to exist without $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ existing. Consider the very simple case of $f(x) = \cos (2 \pi x)$. In this case, $a_n = \cos (2 \pi n) = 1$ for all $n$, so $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 1$. On the other hand, $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ does not exist.